# Discord JS, VoiceConnection.play() breaks with a local music playlist

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, audio-player, playlist

I have a Discord bot and I want it to play local music. While doing this with just one file works, when I tried to play more songs everything brokes down.

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', ((oldState, newState) => { //Call it when a user enter a voice channel

  if (!oldState.channel && newState.member.user !== bot) { //Discard the bot

    if (newState.channelID === l5r_roleplay.id) { //If it's the right vocal channel do things

      counter++; //Counter is use to check when start playing music and when everyone has left. Basically is a counter for the active members inside the vocal channel

      if (counter === 1) { //It starts playing music when the first member join the vocal channel

        l5r_roleplay.join().then(connection => {

          let i = 0;

          shuffle(music_array); //Function to shuffle array

          console.log("Now playing: " + music_array[i])
          connection.play(music_array[i], {volume: 0.2});

        });

      }

    }

  } else if (!newState.channel && oldState.member.user !== bot) { //Someone left

    if (oldState.channelID === l5r_roleplay.id) {

      counter--;

      if (counter < 0) counter = 0;

      if (counter === 0) {

        l5r_roleplay.leave();

      }

    }

  }

}));
```

The code above is a working one since it plays just the first song (music_array is a string array where each string is song name (+ path))

I want it to play all songs in the array, one after another.

I try put it in for loop, in while loop, in external function. I also tryed use the returned StreamDispatcher to handle when the song end and increment the loop/while variable in the handler but nothing.

The behaviour is simple. If I put a loop, it just print in the console and never play the songs.

An example with a simple for-loop, the dispatcher and the console output

```
for (let i = 0; i < music_array.length;) {

            console.log("Now playing: " + music_array[i])
            const dispatcher = connection.play(music_array[i], {volume: 0.2})
            dispatcher.on('speaking', value => {

              if (!value) i++

            })

          }
```

Output:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
---- < Online e operativo >
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
Now playing: ./backbone/l5r/music/The Samurai's Virtue.mp3
```

Comment: `dispatcher.on()` is a non-blocking method, meaning it will not delay each iteration of the `for` loop's execution. That means the loop will repeat itself hundreds of times and remain at `i = 0` each time, until the bot starts/stops speaking (and the bot will only do so after several seconds, giving the loop enough time to execute hundreds of times while `i` is still 0). Though this is not technically an infinite loop, it will be just as problematic because of how many times it will attempt to play the same song. You will definitely need to use a recursive loop instead.

Comment: So the reason why no music plays is because the loop attempts to play "The Samurai's Virtue" hundreds of times in a matter of milliseconds. And it won't stop attempting to do so until the bot stops speaking. But because it keeps triggering the song to play, the song starts over from the beginning each time, so the bot may also never be able to stop speaking. If that is the case, this is indeed an infinite loop. If not, this loop can still be treated like an infinite one in regards to this issue. As aforementioned, a recursive loop would be able to solve this issue, and is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

> dispatcher.on() is a non-blocking method, meaning it will not delay
> each iteration of the for loop's execution. That means the loop will
> repeat itself hundreds of times and remain at i = 0 each time, until
> the bot starts/stops speaking (and the bot will only do so after
> several seconds, giving the loop enough time to execute hundreds of
> times while i is still 0). Though this is not technically an infinite
> loop, it will be just as problematic because of how many times it will
> attempt to play the same song. You will definitely need to use a
> recursive loop instead. – Cannicide

As @Cannicide said, unfortunatly dispatcher.on() is non-blocking.

So here's a solution to the previous problem. We need a recursive function

```
function play(voiceConnection, song, index) {

  if (index === 0) {

    shuffle(music_array);
    song = music_array[0];

  }

  console.log("Now Playing: " + song);
  const dispatcher = voiceConnection.play(song, {volume: 0.2})
  dispatcher.on('speaking', value => {

    if (!value) {

      index = index+1 === music_array.length ? 0 : index+1;

      play(voiceConnection, music_array[index], index);

    }
    
  })

}
```

The first if is used for shuffling the array each time the function is called with index = 0; This happens when we first call the function:

```
play(connection, null, 0);
```

And when we reach the end of the playlist (first line in the second if). This is a personal scenario, since I want the playlist not just to restart on end, but also to re-shuffle.

Comment: I've been using a recursive function for a while now, but I want to know, does this ever have issues after a few thousand songs have played? Wouldn't the recursive depth limit be a problem? I know it's 10,000 or something. But could it ever be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the dispatcher is an async object and plays streamable's asynchronously. So when dispatcher.on() is fired it occurs "outside" your while loop.
Your while loop will forever loop while the dispatcher plays in the background.

The best way to handle this is with a recursive function.
I've been using something like this for a while now and it works very well:

```
//Functions
async function play(bot, message, guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = bot.musicQueue.get(guild.id);

    //Check if a song exists.
    if (!song) {
        if (serverQueue.loop) {
            //Copy finished songs back to songs
            serverQueue.songs = serverQueue.songs.concat(serverQueue.finishedSongs);
            serverQueue.finishedSongs = []; //Clear finished songs

            //Play again and message
            message.WaffleResponse(`Looped `, MTYPE.Information);
            return play(bot, message, guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        } else {
            //Leave on end of music after 5 minutes
            leaveChannelOnNoSong(bot, message, serverQueue);
        }
        return;
    } else {
        //Song details
        const { title, url, duration_ms } = song.song;
        const queuedBy = song.queuedBy.toString();

        //Create readable video object
        var readable = await ytdl(url, { quality: "highestaudio", highWaterMark: 1 << 25 });
        //Create dispatcher and play
        const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
            .play(readable, { highWaterMark: 1, bitrate: 'auto', fec: true, volume: 0.1 })
            .on('start', () => {
                //Send message
                message.WaffleResponse(
                    `Started playing [${title.replace(/(\*|_|`|~|\\|\[|])/g, '')}](${url})` +
                    ` ${queuedBy}\n\n**Song Duration:**\n${(duration_ms / 1000).toString().toTimeString()}`,
                    MTYPE.Information, null, false, null, serverQueue.textChannel
                );
            }).on("finish", () => {
                //Shift songs and play next recursively
                serverQueue.finishedSongs.push(serverQueue.songs.shift());
                return play(bot, message, guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
            }).on('error', (err) => {
                //Send message
                message.WaffleResponse(
                    `[${title}](${url}) encountered an error while streaming. Skipped.`, MTYPE.Error,
                    null, false, null, serverQueue.textChannel
                );
                //Shift songs and play next recursively
                serverQueue.songs.shift();
                return play(bot, message, guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
            });
    }
}
```

On first call is:

```
play(bot, message, message.guild, tempServerQueue.songs[0]);
```